# Writing out a maximal sub-field of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Consider the ring $R = S^{-1} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ where $S$ is the multiplicative set generated by $$\left\{x - a \mid a \in \mathbb{C} \right\} \cup \left\{ y - a \mid a \in \mathbb{C} \right\}. $$

I have shown that $R$ is actually a field, since multiplication is defined as (recall the elements are equivalence classes): $$ [m, s] \cdot [m^{'}, s^{'}] := \frac{m}{s} \cdot \frac{m^{'}}{s^{'}} = \frac{m m^{'}}{s s^{'}} $$ where $m \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $s \in S$. I have shown that $[s,m]$ is the multiplicative inverse of $[m,s]$.

Also, I have proven that any artinian integral domain is a field.

**Problem:** Now, I need to write down a maximal (with respect to inclusion) subfield of $R$. I know that $\mathbb{C}(x) \subset R \subset \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

I don't know how to find this maximal subfield. If I let $K := \left\{x - a \mid a \in \mathbb{C} \right\}$, I was thinking of taking $R^{'} = K^{-1} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. I think it is clear that $R^{'} \subset R$ because $K \subset S$. And $R^{'}$ is again a field.

Also, does $R$ contain a largest sub-field?

Comment: In $R'$, the element $y/1$ is not invertible, so $R'$ is not a field. Actually, note that any field containing $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ also contains $\Bbb{C}(x,y)$. So a maximal subfield of $R$ will not be of the form $K^{-1}\Bbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch $y/1$ is invertible, but $(x+y)/1$ is not

Comment: @Christopher : $y/1$ is invertible in $R$ but not in $R'$, the proposed field.

Comment: Are you sure $R$ is a field? What's the inverse of $x+y$? If you're going to claim that $[s,m]$ is the inverse of $[m,s]$, you have to argue that $m \in S$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch d'oh, sorry